# I can not save my user defined function in my Database in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am using SQL  server 2012. Actually, I am new one in relational database sphere.
I create function in my DB but I can't save it in my Project (current database).
How can I save it to my DB and then I need call this function by query?

I just press "save" button and sql server shows that I need save this file as ".sql" file to folder C:\Users\user-name\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio

Thank's in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to execute your `CREATE FUNCTION ...` statement on the DB where you'd want it to reside and it will be created.

Saving will just save your script. Not add it to your database structure.

See MSDN [Create User-defined Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191320.aspx) for further details and syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use stored procedure

```
Create procedure YourProcedureName
@YOUR
@VARIABLE
@HERE
AS
BEGIN
 YOUR QUERY HERE
END
```

and you can call it

```
YourProcedureName 'Your','Variable','here'
```